# Linq , SQLServer - performance

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one example:

```
select count(1) from product where (product.loaisanpham = 10)
```

=> result = 100

```
select count(1) from product where (product.giasanpham > 10000)
```

=> result = 5000000
Now, I have two query:

```
1. select * from product where (product.loaisanpham = 10 and product.giasanpham > 10000)
2. select * from product where (product.giasanpham > 10000 and product.loaisanpham = 10)
```

**Which is faster (1) or (2)?
I'm using SQL Server**. 
I remember that when I used mongodb, (1) was faster (2)

Comment: "Which is faster (1) or (2)?" - you tell us!

Comment: In mongodb (1) faster. In sql server, I think they are the same